# meta property="og..." не выводит картинку

Tags: html

```
<meta property="og:type" content="profile">
<meta property="og:title" content="title">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://likeavenus.github.io/likeavenus/">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.159524260.4446/flat,800x800,075,t.u2.jpg">
```

Не выводится картинка, при отправке ссылки на страницу в соц.сетях.
В чем причина?

Comment: В каких соц. сетях?

Comment: @Suvitruf VK :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, в каких соц. сетях вы отправляли ссылки, но, как минимум, FB и VK кеширует данные по страницам.

Для FB инвалидировать (да и просто посмотреть, правильно ли мета-теги настроены) можно [тут](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Для VK [тут](https://vk.com/dev/pages.clearCache).

Comment: Сработало) спасибо!

Comment: @RafaelShepard рад, что помогло ^_^